jenkins Credentials Binding Plugin not showing username
I m using jenkins Credentials binding plugin with usernamePassword but apparently after recent update the username is not interpreted correctly.
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: CREDENTIALS, usernameVariable:'user', passwordVariable:'passwd')]) { ... }



Now this was my code:
sh "curl -u \$user:\$passwd http://URl"

which worked perfectly but now I m getting curl -u  :**** => only reads the password.
I switched to just "$user:$passwd" but this gives me a warning that the credentials are exposed. Also it only works with double quotes:'$user:$passwd' => username not interpreted.
Any Ideas ?.

If not too much bother, what's your current version of the Credentials Binding plugin, and what's the previous one (can be found in Installed plugins as the "downgrade to" version)?

using this: 631.v861c06d062b_4
previous one: 681.vf91669a_32e45
But If it is not a version problem then It's better not to update it.
The error happened 2 days ago.

Tried with the latest version - cannot reproduce. Could be an agent specific problem. Or someone edited your secret
